# Passing a reference and a string into a subroutine

Tags: perl

I'm trying to pass a reference to an array, and a string into a function in the form;

```
&function2(\g_array, "String");
```

In my subroutine I want to deference the array so I can evaluate/print it, but when I try to do that it complains that I can't map a string to an array while using strict. What is the best method to do this?

Comment: If, as you say in comments below, you're actually calling the subroutine with `\@g_array` rather than `\g_array` then the problem is going to be within the subroutine where you try to use the parameters. Without seeing that code, it's hard to see how we can help.

Comment: Oh, and if you're learning from a source which tells you to use `&` to call subroutines, then your source is rather suspect (or, at least, horribly out of date).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `use strict` in the current scope. It would have warned you: `bareword "g_array" not allowed`.

If `g_array` is a function, then `\g_array` parses as `\(g_array())`. If it isn't, it parses as `\"g_array"`. So you are actually passing a reference to a string.

What you wanted was to pass an arrayref? Just include the `@` sigil in the variable:

```
function2(\@g_array, "String");
```

Comment: These are the snippets are the part I'm having a problem with

if (&function2(\@g_array,”Just a String!”) != 0) {
    print "No values found for '$g_search'","\n";

sub function2 {
my ($l_array,$variable_two) = map @$_, $_[1];

Comment: @user2361820 That code is in no way complete. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16531658/edit) your question to include the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 3):

If you were using [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html), which you should always do, you would have seen this error:

> Bareword "g_array" not allowed while "strict subs" in use

What that means: `g_array`, without a sigil, is a "bareword." Without strictures turned on, barewords are just made into strings. (Assuming they're not the name of a function.) What you've done is take a reference to the string `"g_array"`.

To take a reference to a an array, use `\@g_array`.

Also, there's generally no reason to use the `&` in front of a function name unless you know why you should.

Comment: Sorry, I just typed that out, I had it as \@g_array. I'll add my actual code below